# Arduino traffic lights

Tags: arduino

This is my code for a simple traffic light setup on an Arduino Uno. I wanted to make a counter that controls the lights according to the value. For this I used an increment in a for loop, this is where my code seems to get stuck, and I have no clue on how to continue. Could some wizard point me in the right direction? And/or whatever needs

```html
int red = 13;
int yellow = 12;
int green = 11;
int counter = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellow, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  changeLights();
}
void changeLights() {

  //Counts to x(15)
  for (counter < 15; ++counter;)
  {
    delay(1000);
  }

  //turn on green lights for when counter is under 6
  if (counter <= 6);
  {
    digitalWrite (green, HIGH);
  }

  //Turns on green and yellow light.
  if (counter >= 6);
  {
    digitalWrite (green && yellow, HIGH);
  }

  //turns off green and yellow light, turns on red light.
  if (counter > 9);
  {
    digitalWrite (green && yellow, LOW); (red, HIGH);
  }

}
```

Comment: You increment until 15 and then check if less than 6 ...does that make sense to you? Edit: I'm not sure of allowed syntax, but for () should have 3 sections..you have two. This isnt wizardry.. Is day-1 fundamentals.

Comment: "for (int counter = 0; counter < 15; ++counter)" 
So how do I get my if's to check for the value in counter all the time? And yes this is sort of first day doing this :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure, if the for() loop works but the arduino reference sayes it:

> Any or all of the three header elements may be omitted, although the semicolons are required.

But i would stay with the "classic" Definition as Long as not needed.

Edit: As answer to the comment (too new to stackoverflow) just put that all into the for Loop.